# Parse system's arguments into the javafx class

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing an javafx application. My application class GUI which extends Application interface contains all the variables of the system and the contructor of the game which in fact contains the connection of the interface with my database.

```
public class GUI extends Application {
   ... \\system variables
   public GUI(String args[]) throws SQLException, InterruptedException {
      ...
      connectionQuestions = questionssqliteConnection.dbConnector();
      connectionUsers = userssqliteConnection.UdbConnector();
   } 
}
```

I wanted to know if there is a possibility to parse inside the constructor of the GUI calls, systems arguments. I tried to add them and I got several errors:

> Exception in Application constructor
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   Exception running application GUI

Is there a way to pass them to my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this is covered in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html).

First note that your `Application` subclass *must* have a no-argument constructor, and that constructor is invoked by the FX Application toolkit to create the instance on which `start(...)` (and `init()`, and other methods) are called. This is why you get the exception when you try to use a constructor taking a `String[]` parameter.

The command line parameters are already passed to the application instance for you, and are available by calling [`getParameters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters--). So you can do

```
public class GUI extends Application {

   // ... system variables

   public init() throws SQLException, InterruptedException {

      // ...

      List<String> args = getParameters().getRaw();

      // process parameters...

      connectionQuestions = questionssqliteConnection.dbConnector();
      connectionUsers = userssqliteConnection.UdbConnector();
   } 

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      // ...
   }
}
```